# PHP Windows Extension config.w32 Linking

Tags: php, window, php-extension, pecl

I am working an extension and adding Windows support. There is an external library I am trying to add in raylib, but having some weird conflicts.

First is GLFW seems to having issues, its not every function but some GLFW functions do not have a link i.e

```
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChoosePixelFormat referenced in function _glfwInitWGL
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateBitmap referenced in function createIcon
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateDCW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateRectRgn referenced in function updateFramebufferTransparency
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteDC referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteObject referenced in function createIcon
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DescribePixelFormat referenced in function _glfwCreateContextWGL
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceCaps referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetPixelFormat referenced in function _glfwInitWGL
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateDIBSection referenced in function createIcon
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp
raylib.lib(rglfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SwapBuffers referenced in function swapBuffersWGL
```

Here is my config.w32 file:

```
ARG_WITH("raylib", "for raylib support", "no");

if (PHP_RAYLIB != "no") {
    raylib_lib_paths = PHP_PHP_BUILD + "\\lib;";
    raylib_include_paths = PHP_PHP_BUILD + "\\include;";

    if (
        //-- Raylib
        CHECK_LIB("raylib.lib", "raylib", PHP_PHP_BUILD + "\\lib") &&
        CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE("raylib.h", "CFLAGS_RAYLIB", PHP_PHP_BUILD + "\\include") &&
        //-- GLFW
        CHECK_LIB("glfw3dll.lib", "raylib", PHP_PHP_BUILD + "\\lib") &&
        CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE("glfw3.h", "CFLAGS_RAYLIB", PHP_PHP_BUILD + "\\include\\GLFW")
        ) {

        ADD_FLAG("LIBS_CLI", "raylib.lib glfw3dll.lib");

        var raylib_sources = "raylib.c raylib-image.c raylib-window.c raylib-text.c raylib-cursor.c raylib-texture.c raylib-utils.c";
        PHP_INSTALL_HEADERS("ext/raylib", "php_raylib.h raylib-image.h raylib-window.h raylib-text.h raylib-cursor.h raylib-texture.h raylib-utils.h");
        EXTENSION("raylib", raylib_sources, true, "/DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1", "php" + PHP_VERSION + "raylib.dll");

    } else {
            WARNING("raylib not enabled; libraries not found");
    }
}
```

The entire source code is available here: https://github.com/joseph-montanez/raylib-php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you have solved the issue. I recently suffered from this issue, and solved it with `LDFLAGS`.

Change the line `ADD_FLAG("LIBS_CLI", "raylib.lib glfw3dll.lib");` to

```
ADD_FLAG("LDFLAGS", '/libpath:"' + raylib_lib_paths + '" "raylib.lib glfw3dll.lib"');
```